# ASP.NET MVC2 Simple Linq Question

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following code:

```
      public ActionResult ViewCategory(string categoryName, string searchCriteria = "Price")
    {
        // Retrieve Category and its associated Listings from the database
        var categoryModel = db.Categories.Include("Listings")
            .Single(c => c.Title == categoryName);

        var viewModel = new ClassifiedsBrowseViewModel
        {
            Category = categoryModel,
            Listings = categoryModel.Listings.ToList()
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

This code returns some listings from a given category.

But I want to re-order these search results based on certain criteria. E.G. Price...

Many Thanks, 
J

Comment: Why would you need to do a GroupBy when you're selecting a single row anyway?

Comment: What are you trying to group by? Why are you including Listings? Is that part of your group by or not related?

Comment: Sorry I have updated my question to add the full code, basically I have a classified site. I have different categories and within those categories I have listings, this page simply retrieves the listings for that specific category... but how do I change the order of those listings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [OrderBy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) or [OrderByDescending()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx) depending upon on requirements.

For example ordering it by highest price -

```
var viewModel = new ClassifiedsBrowseViewModel
        {
            Category = categoryModel,
            Listings = categoryModel.Listings.OrderByDescending(c=>c.Price).ToList()
        };
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the advice upthecreek and misnomer. How would I search by the contents of the search criteria string?

Comment: I am afraid dont completely understand...but if you mean order by  dynamically by string value -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby

Comment: Use a switch statement, test for each string you are expecting, perform a different query in each case... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Listings = categoryModel.Listings.OrderBy(x => x.Price).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that might work, depending on how you present the information:  use something like the jquery tablesorter plugin, and sort the results on the client side.

Obviously, this won't work if there are a lot of results, and you're doing paging, but for a single page of results, presented in a table, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write the Linq is to use the query language:

```
Listings = from item in categoryModel.Listings
           orderby item.Price
           select item;
```